# Change single datasource with multiple comboboxes

Tags: c#, combobox, datasource

I'm currently working on a character generator for a role-playing game. I have a method that rolls ability scores and I have them in an array. I convert the array into a List. Then I point all the combo boxes to the data source. I bind them separately so they all don't change to the same number. Unfortunately, I'm having a lot of problems with removing a number from the lists once it's selected. Here is how it looks so far. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
List<int> abilityList = allAtribs.ToList();
        strCombo.DataSource = new BindingSource(abilityList, null);
        dexCombo.DataSource = new BindingSource(abilityList, null);
        conCombo.DataSource = new BindingSource(abilityList, null);
        intCombo.DataSource = new BindingSource(abilityList, null);
        wisCombo.DataSource = new BindingSource(abilityList, null);
        chaCombo.DataSource = new BindingSource(abilityList, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `List<int>`, create a `BindingList<int>` and store it in a form member.

*Form:*

```
private BindingList<int> abilityList;
```

*Initialization:*

```
// if allAttribs is int[], you can remove .ToList()
abilityList = new BindingList<int>(allAtribs.ToList());
strCombo.DataSource = new BindingSource(abilityList, null);
dexCombo.DataSource = new BindingSource(abilityList, null);
// etc....
```

Then you can simply remove a value from `abilityList` (or add new value, update exiting value) and the change will automatically be reflected in all combo boxes.

This is because `BindingList<T>` in addition of being `IList<T>` also provides standard change notifications recognized by data bound aware components.